# How to rename a duplicate file in same path when uploading it?

Tags: blazor, blazor-server-side

I'm trying to upload some files, but when I upload a file that already exists in the path, it overwrites the existing file. I'm trying to get the files renamed if a file with same name exists in the path, such that if file.pdf gets uploaded, it gets renamed file(1).pdf if there is an existing file that goes by file.pdf.

`Code`

```
public async Task OnInputFile(InputFileChangeEventArgs e)
    {
        selectedFiles = e.GetMultipleFiles();
        Message = $"{selectedFiles.Count} file(s) selected";
        this.StateHasChanged();

        foreach (var file in selectedFiles)
        {
            Stream stream = file.OpenReadStream(maxAllowedSize: 10_000_000);
            var path = Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), "FilePath", file.Name);
            FileStream fs = File.Create(path);
            await stream.CopyToAsync(fs);

            fs.Close();
            stream.Close();
        }
        
        Message = $"{selectedFiles.Count} file(s)   uploaded on server";
        this.StateHasChanged();
    }
```

Can anyone help me resolve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

I think what you need to do is run a check to see if the file aready exists in the path first. After you've built your ***path*** variable, you can check it by adding the following before calling File.Create(path):

```
if (File.Exists(path))
{
    // Change the File path here
    path = Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), "FilePath", <<SOMEPREFIXHERE>>,  file.Name);
}
```

I would maybe recommend using a datestamp to in the new version, as this would offer the most uniqueness and avoid a potential situation where the copy has already been uploaded.

As a better options, you may be better to use a ***while*** instead of the if.  Let's say you're using a index as the prefix, and you already have the base copy and 1 new version, you'll use the loop to continue incrementing the prefix integer, until you end up on a version that doesn't exist:

```
var fileVersion = 1;

While (File.Exists(path))
{
    path = Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), "FilePath", $"{fileVersion}-",  file.Name);
    fileVersion++;
}
```